# How can fetch data from shipping to custom field in sales order grid page

Tags: grid, field, admin

I added custom column to **sales order** page contain the fields: Ordernumber, First name, Last name, streetname, housenumber, additional housenumber, emailaddress, postcode and landcode. But I'm unable to fetch the value of all fields.

Below is what I have tried my level best. Any help will be appreciated.

```
/Ahmad/OrderGrid/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <container name="listing_top">
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <filterInput name="order_items">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">order_items</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order items</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterInput>
        </filters>
    </container>
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="order_items">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Items</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="first_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">First Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="last_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Last Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="street_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Street Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="house_number">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">House Number</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="additional _housenumber">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Additional Housenumber</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="emailaddress">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email Address</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="postcode">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Post Code</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="landcode">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Land Code</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Ahmad/OrderGrid/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Ahmad\OrderGrid\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Ahmad\OrderGrid\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Ahmad/OrderGrid/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Ahmad\OrderGrid\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult;

/**
 * Class Collection
 * @package Ahmad\OrderGrid\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid
 */
class Collection extends SearchResult
{
    /**
     * Initialize the select statement.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        // Add the sales_order_item model to this collection
        $this->join(
            [$this->getTable('sales_order_item')],
            "main_table.entity_id = {$this->getTable('sales_order_item')}.order_id",
            []
        );

        // Group by the order id, which is initially what this grid is id'd by
        $this->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add field to filter.
     *
     * @param string|array $field
     * @param string|int|array|null $condition
     * @return SearchResult
     */
    public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null)
    {
        if ($field === 'products' && !$this->getFlag('product_filter_added')) {
            // Add the sales/order_item model to this collection
            $this->getSelect()->join(
                [$this->getTable('sales_order_item')],
                "main_table.entity_id = {$this->getTable('sales_order_item')}.order_id",
                []
            );

            // Group by the order id, which is initially what this grid is id'd by
            $this->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');

            // On the products field, let's add the sku and name as filterable fields
            $this->addFieldToFilter([
                "{$this->getTable('sales_order_item')}.sku",
                "{$this->getTable('sales_order_item')}.name",
            ], [
                $condition,
                $condition,
            ]);

            $this->setFlag('product_filter_added', 1);
        }

        return parent::addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
    }

    /**
     * Perform operations after collection load.
     *
     * @return SearchResult
     */
    protected function _afterLoad()
    {
        $items = $this->getColumnValues('entity_id');

        if (count($items)) {
            $connection = $this->getConnection();

            // Build out item sql to add products to the order data
            $select = $connection->select()
                ->from([
                    'sales_order_item' => $this->getTable('sales_order_item'),
                ], [
                    'order_id',
                    'product_skus'  => new \Zend_Db_Expr('GROUP_CONCAT(`sales_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR "|")'),
                    'product_names' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('GROUP_CONCAT(`sales_order_item`.name SEPARATOR "|")'),
                    'product_qtys'  => new \Zend_Db_Expr('GROUP_CONCAT(`sales_order_item`.qty_ordered SEPARATOR "|")'),
                ])
                ->where('order_id IN (?)', $items)
                ->where('parent_item_id IS NULL') // Eliminate configurable products, otherwise two products show
                ->group('order_id');

            $itemCollection = $connection->fetchAll($select);

            // Loop through this sql an add items to related orders
            foreach ($itemCollection as $item) {
                $row = $this->getItemById($item['order_id']);
                $productSkus = explode('|', $item['product_skus']);
                $productQtys = explode('|', $item['product_qtys']);
                $productNames = explode('|', $item['product_names']);
                $html = '';

                foreach ($productSkus as $index => $sku) {
                    $html .= sprintf('<div>%d x [%s] %s </div>', $productQtys[$index], $sku, $productNames[$index]);
                }

                $row->setOrderItems($html);
            }
        }

        return parent::_afterLoad();
    }

    /**
     * Get the record count.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSize()
    {
        if ($this->_totalRecords === null) {
            $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
            $this->_totalRecords = count($this->getConnection()->fetchAll($sql, $this->_bindParams));
        }

        return (int) $this->_totalRecords;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGerP.png)

Comment: How does your code look so far? What errors do you get? What else did you try?

Please show your efforts before you ask other to spent time to solve your problems.

Comment: @Jane: Updated my issue with code .. please check

Comment: Maybe you should choose other tags to attract people with more experience here. how about e.g. magento , php and xml?

Next describe exactly how you execute your code and add resulting log messages. Maybe do some debugging to check, where your code goes off the track and add this insights to your question, too.